# Issue calling Oracle Database Function ORA-22922: nonexistent LOB value

Tags: oracle, mule, clob, proc

I am trying to call an oracle database function. The input is a CLOB and the output is a String value (status). Here is the code: payload is a Clob.

```
<jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queryKey="UpdateError" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="DatabaseNCS" doc:name="Database">
    <jdbc-ee:query key="UpdateError"
             value="Call #[output;string;out] := dbpk_bxf_media.track_pse_errors(#[message.payload])"/>
</jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint>
```

I do not get the expected output "OK". This works without any issues when I write a custom java code. Here is the output log (Note the output is ORA-22922: nonexistent LOB value): 
I would like to know what I am doing wrong and any way to fix this issue. Thanks!

```
CallableSqlCommandExecutor: SQL: { Call ? := dbpk_bxf_media.track_pse_errors(?) } input params: [oracle.sql.CLOB@1fbb2176] 

CallableSqlCommandExecutor: Registering output parameters for: { Call ? := dbpk_bxf_media.track_pse_errors(?) } 

CallableSqlCommandExecutor: Executing: { Call ? := dbpk_bxf_media.track_pse_errors(?) } 

CallableSqlCommandExecutor: Command executed successfully: { Call ? := dbpk_bxf_media.track_pse_errors(?) } 

CallableSqlCommandExecutor: Processing resultSets for: { Call ? := dbpk_bxf_media.track_pse_errors(?) } 

CallableSqlCommandExecutor: Processed resultsets: 0 

CallableSqlCommandExecutor: Processing output parameters for: { Call ? := dbpk_bxf_media.track_pse_errors(?) } 

ExecuteSqlStatementStrategy: Obtained result: {output=ORA-22922: nonexistent LOB value}
```

Comment: what is the spec for the function?  Also, does the function do any transactions? (commit/rollback)

Comment: Function doesn't do any transaction processing.It works fine when I call it from a custom Java code from Mule

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this issue by removing the Custom Transformer i used for converting the String to a Clob